# Save EACH regex match to a new txt file (batch)?

Tags: regex, extract

I basically need a program/script that will search a file for regex matches and then save each match to a newly created text file (ie. match_01.txt, match_02.txt, match_03.txt, etc.). NB: it must support multiline matching!

**EDIT :**

This is what I tried using Josha's help (thx:):

I get an error when I try this

**Python Script:**

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'(?s)(?<=Sample)(.*?)(?=EndSample)', flags=re.S)
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    matches = pattern.findall(f.read())

for i, match in enumerate(matches):
    with open('Split/match{0:04d}.txt'.format(i), 'w') as nf:
        nf.write(match)
```

**Command Prompt:**

```
C:\Test\python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 31, in <module>
    nf.write(match)
TypeError: expected a character buffer object
```

test.txt looks something like this:

Sample A1
...
...
...
...
...
EndSample

Sample B4
...
...
...
...
...
EndSample

Sample X6
...
...
...
...
...
EndSample

So I need to match everything between "Sample" and "EndSample" (hundreds of lines in-between) and write each match to its own txt file.
So far it only works if my regex pattern is ie. "Sample". There is 15 matches and it does create 15 txt files in the Split folder but they all contain just the word Sample and nothing more.
Multiline still not working looks like..
And if my regex is this:

> (?s)(Sample)(.*?)

then it also gives me the same error as above. Its like it doesnt like (.*?)  Strange..?

Comment: Which programming language? What have you tried?

Comment: python, as stated above. shouldn't the script above work?

Comment: ok, voted to reopen after your edit. I don't know Python that much, so sorry, I can't help :)

Answer (score 0):

In Python (assuming matches do not span lines):

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'(?s)(?<=Sample)((?:.+?)?)(?=EndSample)', flags=re.S)  # Your regex goes here
with open('path/to/your/file.txt', 'r') as f:
    matches = pattern.findall(f.read())

for i, match in enumerate(matches):
    with open('/path/to/your/match{0:04d}.txt'.format(i), 'w') as nf:
        nf.write(match)
```

Comment: aaahh i need it to span lines though :) thanks for your input though. might you know how to make it capture multiple lines? my regex pattern has to be like this: (?s)(?<=SOMETHING)(.*?)(?=SOMETHING ELSE)                so it captures everything between something and something else.

Comment: so basically extracting data (regex match) from a file and then putting each data/match in its own file.

Comment: For multiline, just add the DOTALL flag `re.S` flag. So `pattern = re.compile(r'\d+', flags=re.S)`. Should do the trick :)

Comment: Hey josha can u see what this error is all about that Im getting? check my edited post above. please and thank you.

Comment: Sorry! Missed the notification for your comment. Maybe try `((?:.+?)?)` instead of `(.*?)`?